# The best, worst, and average-case runtime of a function to check for duplicates?

Tags: java, math, big-o, time-complexity

I'm having some trouble finding the big O for the if statement in the code below:

```
public static boolean areUnique (int[] ar)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.length-1; i++) // O(n)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < ar.length-1; j++) // O(n)
        {
            if (ar[i] == ar[j]) // O(???)
                return false; // O(1)
        }
    }

    return true; //O(1)
}
```

I'm trying to do a time complexity analysis for the best, worst, and average case

Thank you everyone for answering so quickly! I'm not sure if my best worst and average cases are correct... There should be a case difference should there not because of the if statement? But when I do my analysis I have them all ending up as O(n<sup>2</sup>)

- Best: O(n) * O(n) * [O(1) + O(1)] = O(n<sup>2</sup>)
- Worst: O(n) * O(n) * [O(1) + O(1) + O(1)] = n<sup>2</sup>
- Average: O(n) * O(n) * [O(1) + O(1) + O(1)] = O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Am I doing this right? My textbook is not very helpful

Comment: integer comparisons are always O(1)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this line

```
if (ar[i] == ar[j])
```

always takes time Θ(1) to execute.  It does only a constant amount of work (a comparison plus a branch), so the work done here won't asymptotically contribute to the overall runtime.

Given this, we can analyze the worst-case behavior by considering what happens if this statement is always false.  That means that the loop runs as long as possible.  As you noticed, since each loop runs O(n) times, the total work done is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) in the worst-case.

In the best case, however, the runtime is much lower.  Imagine any array where the first two elements are the same.  In that case, the function will terminate almost instantly when the conditional is encountered for the first time.  In this case, the runtime is Θ(1), because a constant number of statements will be executed.

The average-case, however, is not well-defined here.  Average-case is typically defined relative to some distribution - the average over what? - and it's not clear what that is here.  If you assume that the array consists of truly random `int` values and that `int`s can take on any integer value (not a reasonable assumption, but it's fine for now), then the probability that a randomly-chosen array has a duplicate is 0 and we're back in the worst-case (runtime Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)).  However, if the values are more constrained, the runtime changes.  Let's suppose that there are n numbers in the array and the integers range from 0 to k - 1, inclusive.  Given a random array, the runtime depends on

- Whether there's any duplicates or not, and
- If there is a duplicate, where the first duplicated value appears in the array.

I am fairly confident that this math is going to be very hard to work out and if I have the time later today I'll come back and try to get an exact value (or at least something asymptotically appropriate).  I seriously doubt this is what was expected since this seems to be an introductory big-O assignment, but it's an interesting question and I'd like to look into it more.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! However, I have a question about the best case scenario. Would, after breaking out of the if statement to return true, it just continue where it left off in the array since it must determine if every element in the array is unique? And yes, you are right that it is an introductory assignment to big-O

Comment: @user2883256- Nope!  As soon as a `return` statement executes, the function immediately terminates.  This is true for functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

the if itself is O(1);

this is because it does not take into account the process within the ALU or the CPU, so if(ar[i] == ar[j]) would be in reality O(6), that translates into O(1)

Comment: O(6) and O(1) are the same thing.  O(1) just means "bounded from above by some fixed constant," so if there is any maximum amount of work the ALU/CPU does in executing the instruction it will be O(1).

Comment: @templatetypedef That line of thought is a bit grey to me because I often analyze code that has a clear and constant upper bound (i.e. `MAX_SIZE`). But I might still say that the loop has complexity `O(n^2)` even though the constant upper bound makes it technically `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can regard it as O(1).

No matter what you consider as 'one' step,

the instructions for carrying out a[i] == a[j] doesn't depend on the

value n in this case.